# AngularJS select not updating model

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm slowly getting a headache here when working with the select dropdown element in AngularJS. I can pupulate the select box, but it doesn't update the model when an option has been selected.

My service file looks like this (using mockup data for now):

**orderService.js:**

```
app.service('orderService', function ($http) {
this.getProductCategoriesWithProducts = function (userId) {
    return productsMockData();
}
});

/* Mockup data functions */
function productsMockData() {
var category1 = {
    name: "test21",
    products: [
        {
            productId: "1",
            unitPrice: 200,
            description: "test21",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "109051",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        }
    ]
};

var category2 = {
    name: "test4",
    products: [
        {
            productId: "2",
            unitPrice: 100,
            description: "test4",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "109154",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        },
        {
            productId: "3",
            unitPrice: 100,
            description: "test",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                },
                {
                    value: "BOX",
                    name: "BOX"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "109152",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        },
        {
            productId: "4",
            unitPrice: 40,
            description: "asda",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "109151",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        }
    ]
};

var category3 = {
    name: "test45",
    products: [
        {
            productId: "5",
            unitPrice: 400,
            description: "sdfsfss",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "109331",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        }
    ]
};

var category4 = {
    name: "test65",
    products: [
        {
            productId: "6",
            unitPrice: 90,
            description: "asda",
            size: "M/L",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "700107",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        }
    ]
};

var category5 = {
    name: "gdfd",
    products: [
        {
            productId: "7",
            unitPrice: 90,
            description: "asda",
            size: "Past.prod",
            units: [
                {
                    value: "KS",
                    name: "KS"
                }
            ],
            selectedUnit: { value: "", name: "" },
            itemNumber: "900192",
            numOfSelectedItems: 0,
            userComment: "",
            linePrice: 0
        }
    ]
};

var array = [];
array.push(category1);
array.push(category2);
array.push(category3);
array.push(category4);
array.push(category5);

return array;
```

}

My **orderController.js** looks like this:

```
app.controller('orderController', function ($scope, $timeout, orderService, $filter) {
// Constructor for this controller
init();

function init() {
    $scope.selected = {};
    $scope.products = orderService.getProductCategoriesWithProducts(1234);
    console.log($scope.products);
    $scope.orderLines = [];
    $scope.totalSum = 0.00;
    $scope.shippingDate = "";
    $scope.shippingAddress = "";
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.orderComment = "test";
}

$scope.calculateLinePrice = function (product) {
    product.linePrice = product.numOfSelectedItems * product.unitPrice;
}

$scope.calculateTotalPrice = function () {

}
});
```

And my **view** looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="product in productCategory.products">                         
    <td>{{ product.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.size }}</td>
    <td>
        <select ng-model="product.units.selectedUnit" 
                ng-options="u.value as u.name for u in product.units"
                ng-init="u = product.units[1].name">
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

When I take a look at the element inspector in Google Chrome, the options which is output looks like this:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option value="0">KS</option>
```

The main issue (I think) with this is, that I don't full understand what is going on in the select angular code:

```
<select ng-model="product.units.selectedUnit" 
        ng-options="u.value as u.name for u in product.units"
        ng-init="u = product.units[1].name">
</select>
```

Having read the AngularJS documentation about select and ng-options as well as several examples when doing a search, I don't get it :-(

I hope someone can point me in the right direction on this.

Thanks a lot in advance!

**UPDATE with solution**

It was fairly basic, I guess a 5 minute break away from it was needed ;-) It for the model binding it was a typo:

```
<select ng-model="product.units.selectedUnit" ..
```

Should read:

```
<select ng-model="product.selectedUnit" ..
```

and (thanks to Zack) the ng-init="" should read:

```
ng-init="product.selectedUnit = product.units[0]"
```

Comment: I believe it is your ng-init. It should be setting product.units.selectedUnit instead of u

Comment: Hi Zack, thanks a lot for your input :-) I solved the overall problem myself, it was a typo (big, big d'oh!!) It should read ng-model="product.selectedUnit" and not ng-model="product.units.selectedUnit" since selectedUnit is a part of the product object. Dang :-) However, the ng-init="" I still don't get. I've tried with ng-init="product.selectedUnit = product.units[1].name" but it didn't work..

Comment: You were right, Zack. The ng-init="" should be like this: ng-init="product.selectedUnit = product.units[0]"> worked right away! :-) Thanks a lot!